# Query Custom posts within another single custom posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two types of custom posts in wordpress development.One is `Restaurant Listings` and another is `Reviews`.In a single page of `Restaurant listings`I also want to show `Reviews`.

### I have tried this down

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
    // Post content for restaurant listings

    //Post content for "reviews" 
    global $wpdb;
        $title = get_the_title(get_the_ID());
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_title = " . $title;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, "ARRAY_A" );
        print_r($results);

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it does not show anything for `$results` though i have two posts for review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never be directly querying the DB for post listings. WordPress has multiple ways to make the process better and clearer. The entire platform is based on Posts so there are plenty of functions to make your life easy.

This is a very basic example of how to address your need:

```
$reviews = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'reviews'
) );

if ( $reviews ) {
    foreach ( $reviews as $post )
    {
        setup_postdata( $post );
?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

There are many other attributes you could use to select the specific reviews you would like to query. You can also query for meta values and taxonomies.

For further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 0):

You query does not return the desired result, because the SQL string contains an error: you need to wrap the $title in quotes in your SQL string.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_title = '" . esc_sql($title) . "'";
```

Please observe the `esc_sql()` function that prepares the $title variable for use in an SQL query string.

Even better, you could use the `$wpdb->prepare()` method:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_title = %s", $title);
```